# MongoDB: Different return values on .find() at shell access, and at php

Tags: php, mongodb

I started to use MongoDB 2.4.4, and I have a very iritating case for query-ing some post, by field in php.

In the mongoshell, the **db.posts.find({page_id:345671}** (for example) gives me a 293 count of document.

The php equivalent:

```
$connection = new Mongo('mongodb://localhost:27017');
$db = connection->selectDB('post_db');
$posts = $db->posts->find(array('page_id' => 345671));
```

Alway return a zero, but, when the a find array is empty, it gives back the entire collection.

Also, ->explain() and .explain() gaves me different params.

What am I do wrong? There's no sharding, no indexes, just some test data, i'm in the begining of the things.

Comment: it might be caused by type mismatch between the value you are searching for and the actual value in mongodb (e.g. you are searching for int type and page_id's are all strings in mongo). Also, Mongo class is deprecated, try using MongoClient instead

Comment: the page_id property is NumberLong in this case: `"page_id" : NumberLong("3456718765"),`

Comment: i'm not quite sure about that, but you can try setting `ini_set('mongo.native_long', 1);` or wrapping your numbers into MongoInt64 class

Comment: int vs long should not be a problem here. Are you sure you're using the same database? You didn't say whether you did use "use" on the mongoshell.

Comment: sure, there's no other databases, so at the start, i entered `use post_db`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED, many thanks to [Vitaly Muminov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1247149/vitaly-muminov)!** 
"i'm not quite sure about that, but you can try setting ini_set('mongo.native_long', 1); or wrapping your numbers into MongoInt64 class"

**The solution is wrap the number to *MongoInt64*!**